# data size requirements for XGBoost

Tags: xgboost

This is a quick question. If I compare neural network and random forest, the data size requirement is huge in neural network, but a decision tree or random forest can work with less number of records too.

Does any such problem occurs with XGBoost as well? Does it also need a lot of data so that it can go in multiple iterations to reduce the error term?

Answer (score 2):

No. Xgboost is more like traditional ML algorithm. It doesn't need too much data and it also perform better than almost all ML algorithm

Answer (score 2):

The amount of data you need depends on the problem (see this great article on [learning curves](https://machinelearningmastery.com/learning-curves-for-diagnosing-machine-learning-model-performance/)), but in general xgboost is very data efficient like random forests and has found a lot of use where data is expensive to produce as in medicine. Try it out on your data and plot a learning curve - if it is under-fitting, you need more data.